# Manually setting a specific location for Google Maps for debugging

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome, location

Is there a way (in Chrome I would guess) to manually set a specific and precise location for Google Maps to read as the user's location for debug purposes?

I now there is an option to do this when developing for Android as I've seen it as an app permission, but I need to fool a Google Maps web application into thinking I am somewhere I am not (i.e. at a different address) while I test some bits and pieces for various locations.

Comment: Do you mean this? http://www.labnol.org/internet/geo-location/27878/

Comment: That looks like the trick. Will give that a go tomorrow, thanks. Do you want to move that to an answer and I'll accept if it all works as described.

Comment: or may be you can use the chrome extensions https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/location-guard/cfohepagpmnodfdmjliccbbigdkfcgia?hl=en

Comment: For me it works, I use it for my PC. The PC didn't move, but geolocation never returns exact results, so it's a good approach to get the exact location.

Comment: @Dr.Molle The developer console is exactly what I needed.. and more! The device and media emulation in particular have been very useful. If you move that suggestion to an answer I will mark as the approved answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dr Molle's link points to exactly what I was looking for within Chrome.

To summarize:

1. In Google Chrome, press Ctrl+Shift+I on Windows, or Cmd+Opt+I on Mac, to open the Chrome Developer Tools.
2. Now press the Esc (escape) key to open the Console window.
3. Switch to the Emulation tab and choose the Sensors option in the left sidebar.
4. In “Emulate Geolocation coordinates” specify the latitude and longitude coordinates* that you want the browser to use.